# How do I set role in Node JS JWT Authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I'm really new with Node JS and now I'm learning about how to use JWT Authentication in my Rest API
I already make token generator in my login function but when I try to verify the token with setting up some role where if the role equal 2 I could get a data. And now I having trouble because I can't verify my token

**Log in:**

```js
exports.login = function(req, res){
    var post = {
        email : req.body.email,
        password : req.body.password
    }

    var query = "SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ? AND ?? = ?";
    var table = ["user", "password", md5(post.password), "email",post.email];

    query = mysql.format(query,table);

    connection.query(query, function(error, rows){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            if (rows.length == 1){
                //ini 1440 dalam second
                var token = jwt.sign({rows}, config.secret);
                id_user = rows[0].id;
                username = rows[0].username;
                email = rows[0].email;
                tanggal_daftar = rows[0].tanggal_daftar;
                role = rows[0].role;

                var data = {
                    id_user : id_user,
                    access_token : token,
                    username : username,
                    email : email,
                    tanggal_daftar : tanggal_daftar,
                    role : role,
                    ip_address : ip.address()
                }

                res.json({
                     success : true,
                     message : "Token JWT generate",
                     token : token,
                     idUser: data.id_user,
                     username : username,
                     email : data.email,
                     tanggal_daftar : tanggal_daftar,
                     role : data.role
                    });

            }else{
                 res.json({"Error": true, "Message":"Email atau password anda salah"});
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Token check:**

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('../config/secret');

function verifikasi(role){
    return function (req, rest, next){
    // var role = req.body.role;
        //cek authorization header
        var tokenWithBearer = req.headers.authorization;
        if(tokenWithBearer){
            var token = tokenWithBearer.split(' ')[1];
            //verifikasi
            jwt.verify(token, config.secret, function(err, decoded){
                if(err){
                    return rest.status(401).send({auth:false, message:"Token tidak terdaftar!"});
                }else{
                    if(role == 2){
                        req.auth = decoded;
                        next();
                    }else{
                        return rest.status(401).send({auth:false, message:"gagal melakukan otorisasi!"});
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            return rest.status(401).send({auth:false, message:"Token tidak tersedia!"});
        }
    }
}

module.exports = verifikasi;
```

**Index:**

```js
// alamat dengan otoritas khusus
router.get('/api/v1/rahasia', verifikasi(), auth.halamanrahasia);
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also you are not passing the value of role to your verifikasi function.

Comment: The error is i can't verify my account using role in postman, plus i did try to put value in my function but it make other account with different role could get the data

Comment: What response are you getting in the postman after making the request?

Comment: it keep giving code 401 and message failed to authorize

Comment: do console.log(decoded) inside jwt.verify and see what is its value.

Comment: it gave this result
```
asus@DESKTOP-0F5S0RQ MINGW64 ~/Documents/nodejs project/apprestapi (master)
$ node server
Server started on port
Mysql tersambung
{
  rows: [
    {
      id: 13,
      username: 'adha_setiawan',
      email: 'adhasetiawanwiyana@gmail.com',
      password: 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e',
      role: 2,
      tanggal_daftar: '2020-11-04T16:00:00.000Z'
    }
  ],
  iat: 1605182359,
  exp: 1605218359
}
GET /auth/api/v1/rahasia 401 140.670 ms - 53
```

Comment: Change the if statement like this : if( decoded.rows[0].role == 2)

Comment: Thank you, it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in your `if(role == 2)` you should change it to `(decoded.role == 2)`

Edit: change `if(role == 2)` to `if(decoded.rows.role == 2)`

Comment: when you try to access the route `/api/v1/rahasia`  is there any errors logged in terminal where your server runs? Or the code flow doesn't work as you want. And what is the respond of the server when the error happens?

Comment: the code doesn't work as i want and it keep giving code 401 plus message failed to authorize

Comment: The error code is 401 because you have 3 return statements that return status 401. Check what return statement you got. `Token tidak tersedia!` or `gagal melakukan otorisasi!` or `Token tidak terdaftar!` I think you got this one right `gagal melakukan otorisasi!`? I think I found an error. You need to change `if(role == 2)` to `if(decoded.rows.role == 2)`. Because when you created token you pass `var token = jwt.sign({rows}, config.secret);` instead of `var token = jwt.sign(rows, config.secret);`. It wrapped your rows object inside another object that's why you need to use `decoded.rows.role`

Comment: Your welcome. Can you mark me as the right answer :D I added edited part for the right answer :D

Comment: With pleasure 